# Distance between nodes using python networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, nodes, networkx, euclidean-distance

I am new to `NetworkX`, and I need to find the distance between two nodes. I have given it a go, but most of the searches lead to the `DFS`, `Dijkstra`, etc. approaches, which is not my point. I only want the Euclidean distance between two sets of coordinates, where the latter represent nodes in the graph.

Comment: Does the underlying graph have anything to do with the distances that you want to compute? E.g. for selecting the points? If not then surely you just need to compute `((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2 + (p1.z-p2.z)**2)**0.5` for the coordinate pair `(p1, p2)` that you are interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this very easily, as the comment above has pointed out. All you need to do is to implement the [Euclidean distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) inside a `for loop` that iterates over all nodes in your graph. Technically the snippet below focuses on the `edges`, but their length is exactly what you are looking for: the distance between node A and node B (start and endpoint).

You can then save your results in a `dictionary` if you need to run further analysis, such as computing the edge length distribution.

```
import networkx as nx
import math

#Create a test graph
m=2  #Number of initial links
n=100 #Number of nodes
ncols=10 #Number of columns in a 10x10 grid of positions
G=nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, j)
pos = {i : (i // ncols, (n-i-1) % ncols) for i in G.nodes()}

#Compute the node-to-node distances
lengths={}
for edge in G.edges():
   startnode=edge[0] 
   endnode=edge[1]
   lengths[edge]=round(math.sqrt(((pos[endnode][1]-pos[startnode][1])**2)+
                                      ((pos[endnode][0]-pos[startnode][0])**2)),2) #The distance
```

If you then want to compute the edge length distribution, you can use this:

```
import pandas as pd

items=sorted(lengths.items())
values=lengths.values()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Lengths':values})

df['Lengths'].hist(df, bins=10) #Change to as many bins as you want/need
```